# PHP: imagecreatefromstring

Tags: php, gd2

I have a file upload class which returns an image resize object if the file upload is believed to be an image. The construct of the image resize class starts with this:

```
$this->resource = imagecreatefromstring($this->getData());

if (!is_resource($this->resource)) {
  return $this->error(IMAGE_ERR_SOURCE_CREATION_ERROR);
}
```

`$this->getData()` returns the string returned from file_get_contents from `tmp_name` from `$_FILES[..]` array.

The promlem is as follows. It works perfectly fine on my development server `5.3.0` but `imagecreatefromstring()` fails on the production server, `5.3.5`.

Why? I cannot get my head around it, I have compared strings of images from development and product using base64 and they are identical. What do I need to look at thats changed from `.0` to `.5`?

Edit: Yes, GD2 is installed and working correctly. Incidentally, WordPress (3.1) is also installed on this server and all image functionality is working correctly, which is also why I am so puzzled.

**Edit 2**

After debugging with display_errors (I know should have done this first), the error returned is:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): No JPEG support in this PHP build
```

Does this mean I have to reinstall GD with JPEG support or can it be enabled once installed, IE now?

Comment: Does the PHP installation actually have support for the image format you're trying to use? Check phpinfo for the supported codecs.

Comment: Can you define "fails" more precisely for us? What image format is the data?

Comment: run this code 
 $handle = fopen('img.jpg', 'r');

 $contents = fread($handle, filesize('img.jpg'));

 $image = imagecreatefromstring($contents);

 header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

 imagejpeg($image);

 fclose($handle);

Comment: and Test if this function is working or not.

Comment: I wish I could.. It just returns false, no errors at all. The function just returns false..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure you do have GD on the production server (using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` or `$> php -m`) and that is configured correctly (using `$> php --re GD` and `$> php --ri GD`).
2. Enable display errors on production server (temporally)
3. If [2] fails, use `error_reporting(E_ALL)`
4. Run script testcase through SSH on production server and see if it fails as well (it should)
5. Using [4], run it through `strace` (if on linux) or TraceNT (on windows) and see where the error started out from.

Comment: Ahhhhh. I may have used error_reporting(E_ALL); but not display_errors. Massive fail on my part... See question for update.

Comment: If you can't get it to write anything (check logs as well) you'll have to try my 4/5 methods. Strace is quite powerful, though I'm afraid you need someone quite knowledgeable in linux (me excluded).

Comment: Well, the error is pretty self-explanatory. Mission accomplished. :). With regards to your last question, I'm not sure, it depends on the build. In my case, I could just replace the GD library, but I'm not sure about yours. I suppose you could back up your GD copy and throw in a new one.

Comment: Not quite, as how come WordPress is able to upload JPEGs fine?

Comment: Well, you can upload exe files if you wanted to, PHP won't complain ;). Did you tried resizing them (from WP)? WP is clever, it might have some fail overs - such as resizing by HTML/CSS if it failed via PHP.

Comment: @Matt WordPress has a lot of fairly smart code for falling back to dumber behaviour if the PHP version it's running on lacks support for certain image functions (see WordPress's `wp-includes/media.php` code.) It's perfectly possible to upload images, just as files, without GD support for JPEG; WordPress is probably just coping as best it can after that point (it might, say, be displaying full-size images with the display sizes set to thumbnail size on your page, instead of rescaling to generate real thumbnails, for example.)

Comment: You are indeed correct. WordPress hasnt been resizing JPEGs, only PNGs (and probably GIFs but we dont use them ;)). Thanks alot, we are looking into enabled JPEG support now. +1

Comment: Welcome, glad to be of help. :) Good luck.